# VirtualBox - convert VBOX+VDI to OVA without registering the VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, conversion

I have a VirtualBox virtual machine on my Windows host. On my Linux guest I make (by `vbox-img` in a script) a .vdi disk image for another virtual machine. I have .vbox file for that virtual machine as well. Currently, I cannot run this second virtual machine inside the first virtual machine, nor can I register it with `vboxmanage registervm` (not everything needed for this is installed; for example, there is no /dev/vboxdrv), and neither I intend to. But I want to export it as OVA.

Is it possible to make the .ova without registering the VM? I can install missing stuff or convert windows-side, just making sure I am not missing some easy option to do it in the same script building .vdi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out OVA is just a tar archive with VMDK + OVF. VMDK is disk image and can be built by `vbox-img` either from RAW or from VDI as usual. OVA is an XML file that could be kept around and reused to build new versions of the OVA. So, just replacing the VMDK of existing OVA does the trick just fine.